# Pandas Label-based Selection: Accessing Data Index Values with Quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm struggling with using the `loc` operator when the data index value has quotes in them.

[image: Data]

I have tried using:

```
air_travels.loc[:, ['Month', '"1960"']]
air_travels.loc[:, ['Month', "\"1960\"" ]]
air_travels.loc[:, ['Month', """ "1960" """]]
```

when accessing the Month and "1960" columns, but I would always receive the following error:

> KeyError: 'Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported.'

The code works fine when working with just the Month column.

What should I be using instead?

Comment: a. better paste text than pic (can use print of df.to_clipboard), b. seems month is the name of your index not a columns (check with df.columns), c. try df['"1960"']

Comment: df.columns gives me: Index(['Month', '1958', ' "1959"', ' "1960"'], dtype='object'). Not very sure why but once I pasted  ' "1960"' into the code (instead of '"1960"') it ended up working (the only difference was a space).